# Rewrite request on one domain to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to re-write requests going to

```
example.com/folder1/folder2/*
```

to

```
subdomain.example.com/folder1/folder2/*
```

This should only be for requests going to that sub-folder not for the entire example.com domain, i.e. if it goes example.com/folder5, it shouldn't be touched.  Here is what I have, but it's just returning "File does not exist: /folder1/folder2" for folder1/folder2 since it doesn't exist on the example.com HTTP server.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^folder1/folder2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in htaccess on document root of `domain.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(folder1/folder2.*)$ https://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I had to remove \ before .com but otherwise worked perfectly, thanks!